# How to read in data from local port in Java?

Tags: java, port

If localhost:port# was transmitting data and you wanted to read the data via Java to turn it into a string and display it, is there a library for that? Otherwise, how would you go about that?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't get it, why the down vote?

Comment: 3 ppl voted to close this as too vague.  I'm not an expert in Java, so I can only explain my question with high level details. >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has several utility classes to support those operations, such as [Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) (for connecting to the local port), [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (to build a string), and [JTextArea](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) (to display the data in a GUI).

Comment: Thanks.. Sockets is the key!!